# x-frame-options header doesn't prevent showing site in iframe

Tags: iframe, clickjacking

For my site I see that  among response headers there is `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`. Still I can preview my  site in  iframe of some different site, for instance [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_Iframe). But I expected not to. I assume that this is back-end work to add some  more setting that would prevent the site from rendering in iframe? I thought that if it returns the above header the security functionality preventing showing site in iframe is already in place. Isn't it?

UPDATE: It's my fault I didn't specify that this header is returned for each  xhr but there is no such  header for static resources (html, js, css, images). Might that be a reason?

UPDATE2: I've asked BE guys to provide the  header for static resources too. After implementation I'll share whether it helps or not.

Comment: it should be working. What browser are you using?

Comment: Your link is just a default w3schools demo. Perhaps you mean to show us different code?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara, no I didint mean to show something different, I just inserted my  site link into iframe src attribute in this tutorial for testing purpose

Comment: @tim it was Chrome Version 55.0.2883.87, also checked in Firefox Version 50.1.0. I thought that its server that is  responsible for serving content or not

Comment: Something probably isn't what it seems then.

Comment: You confirmed you are indeed receiving the header in your browser?

Comment: The server doesn't know whether the page is being requested in an iframe, so it will send the response and the browser checks the headers to see if it's allowed.

Comment: Which browser you are using. few browsers may not validate the security settings in the headers. Secondly clear cache and try again. this might happen because of cached requests too.

Comment: Chrome Version 55.0.2883.87, also checked in Firefox Version 50.1.0

Comment: maybe post the url to your site so we can verify that the headers look right?

Comment: @mcgyver5, I can't, it did not go live yet

Comment: I expected not.  Is it possible you have set the header twice?

Answer (score 1):

I asked that the URL be posted so more eyes can examine the header.

If that can't be done, check the following by looking at the header as your browser sees it in the developer tools.

If this header is set more than once, it can cause the directive to fail because the browser will condense multiple instances of the same header into one so that it becomes:

```
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN,SAMEORIGIN
```

and this value is not one of the three allowed so the header will be ignored.

For example, if your web server sets it and then code in the application sets it again, it will happen.

source:
https://blog.qualys.com/securitylabs/2015/10/20/clickjacking-a-common-implementation-mistake-that-can-put-your-websites-in-danger

Comment: I have a site where this header (with same value) is set twice - looks just like the 'condensed' example (`SAMEORIGIN,SAMEORIGIN`) and it still works properly in the two browsers I have tested.